# Tengo este listview pero me imprime el request 2 veces

Tags: android, android-listview

```
public class Trabajos extends Fragment {
public static TextView trabajo1;


public Trabajos() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trabajos, container, false);

    ListView trabajos = view.findViewById(R.id.listTrabajos);


    TrabajosAdapter trabadapt = new TrabajosAdapter();
    trabajos.setAdapter(trabadapt);    //Asignacion del adapatador a la listView

    return view;
}

///////////////////Adaptador Trabajos//////////////////////////
class TrabajosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return Array.trabajox.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    public class Holder {
        TextView trabajo;
        Button accion;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder = new Holder();

            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_trabajos_items, null);
            holder.trabajo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trabajov);
            holder.accion = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.accionv);

            holder.trabajo.setText(Array.trabajox.get(position));
            holder.accion.setText(Array.accionx.get(position));


            /////////////////////pantallas vicente////////////////////////////
            holder.accion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intento = new Intent(getContext(), asignacion.class);
                    startActivity(intento);

                }


            });


            return convertView;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A que te refieres con que imprime el request dos veces?